# Why is it ok to have an index with lists as values but not ok for columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the `numpy.array` `i`

```
i = np.empty((1,), dtype=object)
i[0] = [1, 2]

i

array([list([1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

**Example 1**
*`index`*

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1], index=i)
df

        0
[1, 2]  1
```

**Example 2**
*`columns`*
But

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1], columns=i)
```

Leads to this when I display it

```
df
```

> ```
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
> ```

However, `df.T` works!?

---

**Question**
Why is it necessary for index values to be hashable in a column context but not in an index context?  And why only when it's displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of how pandas internally determines the string representation of the `DataFrame` object. Essentially, the difference between column labels and index labels here is that the column determines the format of the string representation (as the column could be a float, int, etc.).

The error thus happens because pandas stores a separate formatter object for each column in a dictionary and this object is retrieved using the column name. Specifically, the line that triggers the error is https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d1accd032b648c9affd6dce1f81feb9c99422483/pandas/io/formats/format.py#L420

Answer (score -1):

The "unhashable type" error usually means that the type, list in this case, is mutable. Mutable types aren't hashable, because they may change after they have produced the hash code. This happens because you are trying to retrieve an item using a list as a key, but since a key has to be hashable, the retrieval fails.

Comment: There is no key-based retrieval going on anywhere.